# Web host without template with email service?

Tags: web, web-hosting

I am trying to host my domain with email support. I couldn’t find any information in website. Is anyone know hosting service with no templates with email support?

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

It is free to use [google appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/) which has email support. You will be able to use an email such as my_name@my_project_name.appspotmail.com